# SimpleDateFormat of Date says this is the 251st day of September?

Tags: java

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class SysDate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(
                // new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/DD HH:mm:ss")
                // right way
                new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
                        .format(new Date()));
    }
}
```

2016/09/251 14:08:27

Process finished with exit code 0

Better
2016/09/07 14:19:03

Process finished with exit code 0

Fixed.  Thanks.

Comment: what is DD? shouldnt it be dd?

Comment: `D` is day of year `d` is day of month. See: [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: @VuralAcar .. indeed it is.  Thanks.  dd gave the expected answer.

Comment: that was what I meant  Jorn Vernee :) thanks Jorn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
```

`D = Day in year`

`d = Day in month`

Answer (score 0):

"DD" is Day in year, as in the 251st day of the year. You want

```
yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments.. use dd for the day here. Thanks for fast responses.

Answer (score 0):

Uppercase D will give you the day in the year, lowercase d will give you the day of the month.